# ReactJS parent/child list items not rendering properly after an item is removed

Tags: reactjs, parent, children

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wbellman/ghuw2ers/6/

In an application I am working on, I have a parent container (List, in my example) that contains a list of children (Hero, in my example).  The list is governed by an outside object.  For simplicity I declared the object directly in the JS.  (In my real application the data store is properly namespaced and so forth.)

The problem I have is in the list I have three elements, if I remove an item from the middle, the rendered list appears to remove the last element.  However the outside object reflects the proper list.

For example:

- My list has the elements: cap, thor, hulk
- If you remove "thor", "cap" and "thor" are rendered
- The heroList reflects "cap" and "hulk" as it should

I am relatively new to ReactJs, so there is a good chance my premise is fundamentally flawed.

Note: The example reflects a much more complex application.  It's structured similarly for purposes of demonstration.  I am aware you could make a single component, but it would not be practical in the actual app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code from JSFiddle:

```
  var heroList = [
    { name: "cap" },
     { name: "thor"},
    { name: "hulk"}
  ];

  var List = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      console.log("heros", heroList);
      return {
        heros: heroList
      };
    },

    onChange(e){
      this.setState({heros: heroList});
    },

    removeHero(i,heros){
      var hero = heros[i];
      console.log("removing hero...", hero);
       heroList = _.filter(heroList, function(h){ return h.name !== hero.name;});
      this.setState({heros:heroList});
    },

    render() {
      var heros = this.state.heros;

      var createHero = (hero,index) => {
        return <Hero hero={hero} key={index} onRemove={this.removeHero.bind(this,index,heros)}/>;
      };


      console.log("list", heros);

      return (  
        <ul>
          {heros.map(createHero)}
        </ul>
       )
    }
  });

  var Hero = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
      return {
        hero: this.props.hero
      }
    },

    render() {
      var hero = this.state.hero;
      return (
        <li>Hello {hero.name} | <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onRemove}>-</button></li>
      );
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
    <List />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

Additional: I was having problems copying the code from JSFiddle, anything I broke by accident should work in the JSFiddle listed at the top of this question.

**Edit:**

Based on the commentary from [madox2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741871/madox2), [nicole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2664355/nicole), [nuway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088556/nuway) and [Damien Leroux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346701/damien-leroux), here's what I ended up doing:

https://jsfiddle.net/wbellman/ghuw2ers/10/

I wish there was a way to give everyone credit, you were all a big help.

Comment: You should add unique keys to your `Hero` elements, not just array indexes

Comment: Wow.  That worked.  https://jsfiddle.net/wbellman/ghuw2ers/7/  However, nuway's answer fixes it and I don't have to refactor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is with the keys used. Since the key is taken from the index, that key has already been used and thus the hero with that key is shown.

change it to `key={Math.random() * 100}` and it will work

Comment: It works but it forces to re-render all Hero component at each rendering process. It is not recommended at all. Instead, use the solution given by @nicole

Comment: I agree. @nicole's answer is a better solution

Comment: I also agree, but in my actual application my child has legitimate state that I can't do away with.  I ended up doing was storing a randomized index based on the principal you suggested.  So...  var heros = [{ id: Math.random() * 100, name:"cap"}]... this prevents the re-render, keeps my field identifiable, and allows me to keep my child's state.  Though if there's a better way I'd be up for it.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your Hero class to this fixed the issue of displaying the wrong hero name for me:

```
var Hero = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <li>Hello {this.props.hero.name} | <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onRemove}>-</button></li>
    );
  }
});
```

i.e. I removed the local state from the class and used the prop directly.

Generally speaking, try to use the local store only when you really need it. Try to think of your components as stateless, i.e. they get something through the props and display it, that's it.

Along these lines, you should consider passing the hero list through the props to your List component as well.

Comment: As I explained above, though my example makes silly use of state, my actual application has a legitimate state I can't get rid of.  As for passing in the list, I agree, I was sloppy on my example.

Comment: My mental model currently is that if you have data in a component's internal state and also outside, there is something strange going on... I'm trying to only have one or the other, but not both with the same data. Have you considered using a more sophisticated state management system like Redux? That might perhaps help you get a more unified view on your data.

Comment: Again, don't get too caught up in the example.  I just hacked something together to illustrate the problem.  It is not representative of the entire app.  The design on the fiddle is admittedly awkward, but it's not so in the app.  The app each "list item" contains multiple fields pointing different data and certain field change based on the data in that panel.  Example: each panel describes a type of car for manufacture.  I just didn't understand the "key" field.

Answer (score 0):

if you really have problems with managing your data you should use Flux or Redux.

in this code:

```
heroList = _.filter(heroList, function(h){ return h.name !== hero.name;});
```

i just dont get why you filer the `heroList` instead of `this.state.heros`? every time you add or remove a hero, the heroList in your current scope shouldnt be kept in state? the global `heroList` is just the initial state.

Comment: In the real application I need to keep track of the original list, and I have multiple filtered containers with other fields that dictate the particular filtered list for each.  Example states and cities.  Each new address panel would filter cities according to the selected state.  To make matters more interesting I have to front load the application data so all city and state data is acquired on page load not individual ajax requests.  It's not ideal but it's the requirement for this app.